# Delete row(s) depending on duplicte value(s) in column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame of this structure

```
Row;Value
1;200
2;300
3;300
4;600
5;450
6;450
```

and I am trying to delete all those rows that have a duplicte number in the Value column

BUT I always want to keep the the row of last equal value.

My correct example would yield accordingly:

```
1;200
3;300
4;600
6;450
```

I tries with no success

```
filtered_df <- df %>%
  group_by(Value) %>%
  filter(row_number() == n())
```

as well as

```
data_modified <- data %>% 
  distinct(Value, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: just do `unique(df)` or even `distinct(df)`

Comment: `df  %>% group_by(value) %>% slice_tail(n=1) %>% arrange(row)`

Comment: either use `slice_tail(n=1)` or `duplicated(date, fromLast = TRUE)`